# using autosys to start and monitor sql server jobs

Tags: autosys

I'm looking for a solution using autosys monitor sql job as following:

1. kick off a sql server job
2. monitor the job status
3. if the job failed, restart at the step where it failed
4. email notification if job failed or not running at, let say 3 am.

I'd appreciate pointers or example of how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score -1):

Since i did not get enough information on using autosys to start/monitor sql jobs. I created an ssis package for this purpose. I use autosys to start/monitor the ssis package, however. The reason for this is to get notification when there is issue with the sql server itself (reboot - causing job to be suspended, network issue - sql server is not reachable, etc...)